# VSCode Unity OmniSharp .NETFramework not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I get this message in the output of VSCode

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
 The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. 
To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version 
or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the
Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

this is what my `dotnet` output looks like

```
~ dotnet --info                                    
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.106
 Commit:    aa79b139a8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.106/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.4
  Commit:  f95848e524

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.106 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

With this error I can't get any IDE features for C# in VSCode.

Comment: As .NET Framework 4.7 is only available for Windows, I don't think you can develop for it on Mac OS X

Comment: A far of guess, but have you tried installing the latest version of Mono? installed Mono V5.18.0 from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ Might help clear the issue with missing .net 4.7.1.

Comment: @MichaëlHompus i was able to develop unity c# with vscode on macos for the past 2 years. with my new mac it doesnt work

Comment: @vsarunov yes i have tried it, it did not help

Comment: @vsarunov I've tried to install mono again and this time I've used the v5.20.1 version and it worked, thanks

Comment: I have posted as an answer.

Comment: Complete reference how to setup Unity with VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install latest [stable Mono Version](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable) should fix the issue for this one, if anyone faces a similar issue.

Or try a different one until it is resolved, might be some mono versions preventing this.

Answer (score 10):

- Close VS Code.
- Download and install Microsoft [.NET Framework 4.7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56119).
- Download and install [Microsoft's .NET Framework SDK any version with start 4.X](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)
- In VS Code, open `Assembly_CSharp.csproj` file and change `TargetFrameworkVersion` to what you installed .NET Framework **SDK** version.

You should have both .NET framework and targeting sdk installed for a particular version.

This is a temporary solution because `targetFrameworkVersion` always changes to unity defaults when you close the editor

Comment: His build environment is Mac OS X. All of your links are windows executables only. Wrong OS.

Comment: I just uninstalled my old .NET Framework, and installed the currently newest versions. It fixed it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (Unity 2022.3.3f1):

- Install C# VS Code plugin
- Download and install [4.7.1 Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks#supported-versions-framework) (you will need to scroll past .NET Core to .NET Framework) (this version number may be different, but it will appear in the `OUTPUT` tab of VSCode as the version of C# you are using with unity.)

  - The file will look like `ndp471-devpack-enu.exe`
- Download and install [.NET sdk for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks#supported-versions-table) (same download as [this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/sdk-for-vs-code)). This will add `dotnet` to your PATH and get VSCode to recognize it. Omnisharp/Intellisense did not work for me without this step.

  - The file will look like `dotnet-sdk-6.0.300-win-x64.exe`
- In Unity, Go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools and ensure `Visual Studio Code` is the External Script Editor. Press `Regenerate project files`
- Restart PC

You shouldn't need to change `settings.json` or anything else